# How can Toolbar with overflow menu be created with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can menu icons of Toolbar can be turned into overflow in Compose?

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(text = "LayoutsCodelab")
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
                }

                IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Refresh)
                }

                IconButton(
                    onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Call)
                }

            }
        )
    },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigationLayout()
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    PhotoCard(Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
}
```

I want only one of the icons in Toolbar menu to be visible while others to be added to overflow menu like done with xml using `app:showAsAction="never"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_sign_out"
    android:title="@string/toolbar_sign_out"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to provide the OverFlowMenu yourself, e.g.:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewOverflowMenu() {
    OverflowMenuTest()
}

@Composable
fun OverflowMenuTest() {
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text("Title") },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Favorite)
            }
            IconButton(onClick = { showMenu = !showMenu }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.MoreVert)
            }
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = showMenu,
                onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }
            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Refresh)
                }
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Call)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Edit: Updated for Compose 1.0.0-beta08

Comment: With the latest version of compose.material3-android (1.2.1) this way of creating the DropdownMenuItem is deprecated. Text and Icon composable should be passed as a parameter.  Use `leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon`                      
 
`DropdownMenuItem(
 trailingIcon= {  Icon(Icons.Filled.Refresh, contentDescription = "refresh") }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })`

Answer (score 25):

I modified a bit @jns's answer to make it more modular and reusable.
This is the reusable OverflowMenu:

```
@Composable
fun OverflowMenu(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    IconButton(onClick = {
        showMenu = !showMenu
    }) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.more),
        )
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = showMenu,
        onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used inside the TopAppBar:

```
TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.my_title))
        },
        actions = {
            OverflowMenu {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text("Bookmarks")
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

We can possibly add icons to DropDownMenuItems if desired. And these items can be extracted as reusable composables as well. If there are other action buttons that you want to show as iconified buttons on the menu(i.e. show as action), you should put them before the OverflowMenu.

```
TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.bookmark))
        },
        actions = {
            //This icon will be shown on the top bar, on the left of the overflow menu
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.FavoriteBorder, stringResource(R.string.cd_favorite_item))
            }
            OverflowMenu {
                SettingsDropDownItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
                BookmarksDropDownItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
            }
        }
    )
```

.

```
@Composable
   fun SettingsDropDownItem(onClick : () -> Unit) {
      //Drop down menu item with an icon on its left
      DropdownMenuItem(onClick = onClick) {
         Icon(Icons.Filled.Settings,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.settings),
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))
         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
         Text(stringResource(R.string.settings))
     }
  }

  @Composable
  fun BookmarksDropDownItem(onClick : () -> Unit) {
     //Drop down menu item with an icon on its left
     DropdownMenuItem(onClick = onClick) {
        Icon(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.bookmark),
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text(stringResource(R.string.bookmark))
    }
}
```

Comment: `showMenu` could also be done as:
`val showMenu = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }`
`showMenu.value = !showMenu.value`, using `showMenu.value` everywhere else `showMenu` is currently used

Answer (score 13):

Inspired by `@jns`'s answer,  I made an `ActionMenu` composable which takes a list of `ActionItemSpec` objects. and displays them with an overflow menu if necessary. I modelled the `ActionItemSpec` a bit like the old XML menu item entries, but added an onClick lambda.

It's used like this

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewActionMenu() {
    val items = listOf(
        ActionItemSpec("Call", Icons.Default.Call, ActionItemMode.ALWAYS_SHOW) {},
        ActionItemSpec("Send", Icons.Default.Send, ActionItemMode.IF_ROOM) {},
        ActionItemSpec("Email", Icons.Default.Email, ActionItemMode.IF_ROOM) {},
        ActionItemSpec("Delete", Icons.Default.Delete, ActionItemMode.IF_ROOM) {},
    )
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text("App bar") },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Menu, "Menu")
            }
        },
        actions = {
            // show 3 icons including overflow
            ActionMenu(items, defaultIconSpace = 3)
        }
    )
}
```

and the preview looks like this

[image: Navigation hamburger, "App bar" title, phone icon, send icon, three vertical dots overflow menu]

Full pastebin is here: https://gist.github.com/MachFour/369ebb56a66e2f583ebfb988dda2decf

Comment: Well done machfour. A slight tweak might be to use DSL style definition of the contents of the ActionMenu: "ActionMenu(...) {  ActionItemSpec(...) ActionItemSpec(...) ... }".

Comment: Great suggestion @Duane. This would definitely look nicer and is more idiomatic Compose code. It's quite a refactor since the Compose code is currently all in ActionMenu, and ActionItemSpec is essentially just a data class, but I will consider it

Comment: @Duane actually, it's not really possible to do this while also keeping the ability to dynamically adjust the number of items displayed as icons. The ActionMenu has to know how to lay out each ActionItem either as an icon or entry in the overflow menu.